# get pytest exit code from shell script

Tags: python, shell, pytest

I'm running pytest test from shell script.
The relevant line in the script looks something like:

```
pytest pytest_tests --param=$my_param
```

According to pytest documentation, "Running pytest can result in six different exit codes" (0-5). 
My question is how can I get this exit code from the script?
I tried something like

```
exit_code = pytest pytest_tests --param=$my_param
echo $exit_code
```

But I got this:

```
exit_code: command not found
```

How can I get it? Or is there a better way to get pytest results in the shell script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a command runs its exit code should be available via the [`$?` variable](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html). Try something like this:

```
pytest pytest_tests --param=$my_param
echo Pytest exited $?
```

This works in Bash, and should work in the regular `sh` Bourne shell and zsh as well.

If you need to assign this to another variable, use

```
my_var=$?
```

Note the lack of spaces.