# How to force pytest return error code error code

Tags: pytest

I have following structure:
Koholo job that calling python script, the script returns error code (1 - failed, 0 - passed) as it ends. Koholo wait for the error code to continue to next job step (next scrips).
Now instead of python script I'm running pytest scrips (with command: python -m pytest test_name) but pytest is not returning error code, so the Kohola job timeouts.
Please let me know if there is a way that pytest will return error code as it finish's?

Comment: Seems like you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601608/get-pytest-exit-code-from-shell-script) answer.

Answer (score 1):

example you can pass any pytest argument that you normaly pass in the cli, i am just using the markers as an example

```
import sys
import pytest

results = pytest.main(["-m", "my_marker"])
sys.exit(results)
```

if you want more details
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/exit-codes.html

Answer (score 0):

when pytest finish it calls `pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus)` method.
try to add `sys.exit(exitstatus)` to this method.

```
import sys


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """ whole test run finishes. """
    sys.exit(exitstatus)
```

also you can check by running this script to check the exit code

```
start /wait  python -m pytest test_name
echo %errorlevel%
```